# await fs writefile with puppeteer doesn't wait until file has written before continuing event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer, fs

I am using `nodemon` to run my application with `nodemon index.js`

In my `index.js` file is where I initialise my functions using `Puppeteer`

## INDEX.JS

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const reddit = require("./reddit");

(async () => {
  // ...
  await reddit.initialize();
  await reddit.login(username, password);
  const results = await reddit.getResults();
  console.log('got results');
})();
```

This all works as expected.

In my `initialize()` function, I set up the `Puppeteer` options

## REDDIT.JS

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

const self = {
  browser: null,
  page: null,

  initialize: async () => {
    // Select browser
    self.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      slowMo: 10,
      defaultViewport: null
    });
    //  create new page
    self.page = await self.browser.newPage();
  },
};

module.exports = self;
```

Where I am having an issue is my `getResults()` function

```
getResults: async () => {
    // ...
    await self.page.goto(SUBREDDIT_URL(reddit), { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
    const elements = await self.page.$$(
      '#siteTable > div[class*="thing"]:not(.promoted)'
    );
    const results = [];
    
    await Promise.all(
      elements.map(async element => {
        // ... logic done that pushes items to results array
      })
    );
    console.log("about to write to file");

    await fs.writeFile(
      `${__dirname}/results.json`,
      JSON.stringify(results),
      err => {
        console.log("currently writing");
        if (err) return false;
        return true;
      }
    );

    console.log("finished writing to file");
    
    return await Promise.all(results);
}
```

When I run this I get the following in the console

```
about to write to file
finished writing to file
got results
currently writing
```

I was expecting

```
about to write to file
currently writing
finished writing to file
got results
```

Where have I gone wrong here that my function finishes before the file written?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `require('fs').promises` instead of `require('fs')`.

Comment: @Titus Not 100% sure if that's doing anything different as I am not getting `currently writing` logged in the console but the file does update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular version of `fs.writeFile()` does not return a promise and thus the `await` does nothing.  `await` only does something useful if you are awaiting a promise.

The latest versions of node.js have promise support for the fs module.  You can do so like this:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function someFunc() {
    await fsp.writeFile('someFilename', someData);
    // other code here
}
```

Note, it's my convention to name the imported module `fsp` instead of `fs` to make it more obvious that it is different than the plain `fs`.